# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un botón cambie su icono según si está normal, activo o presionado?

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen, botón

Mi problema es que **no sé si puedo hacer un botón que cambie su icono según su estado** ya que los botones normales son muy anti estéticos. les agradecería si me ayudaran a encontrar una solución, o darme una idea de como resolverlo.

Otra duda que tengo es **si puedo quitar** el efecto de "hundimiento" del botón al ser presionado.

[image: Imagen concepto]

**Esto es lo que quiero conseguir.**

[image: Interfaz de mi programa]

Esta es una versión resumida de mi interfaz, y como ven, ese sería un botón "añadir", un poco grande xd, pero bueno, eso se arregla luego.

Aquí la parte superior de mi ventana.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, PhotoImage

root=Tk()
root.title("Notir")
root.geometry("677x450")

barra_superior= Frame(root)
barra_superior.config(height="430", bg="white")
barra_superior.pack(fill="x", side="top", before=frame_alarmas)

reloj_superior= Label(barra_superior, text="", font=("ArcaMajora3-Bold", 19), bg="white", fg="#0092CB", padx=10)
reloj_superior.pack(side="left")

icono_añadir_alarma=PhotoImage(file="icono_añadir.png")
boton_añadir_alarma=Button(barra_superior, image=icono_añadir_alarma, activebackground="white", bg="white", bd=0)
boton_añadir_alarma.pack(side="right")

def update_clock():

    """
    "update_clock" actualiza cada 1 segundo
    el reloj que se encuentra en "barra_superior".
    """

    update= time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    reloj_superior.configure(text=update)
    barra_superior.after(1000, update_clock)

update_clock()
root.mainloop()
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Como parámetro del `button` podrias pasar `relief = "solid"` para dar algún efecto al botón. Las opciones de ese parámetro son:

```
flat, groove, raised, ridge, solid o sunken
```

Cada uno da un efecto distinto que te podría ayudar. Te anexo un pequeño ejemplo:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox

top = tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
   MessageBox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack, relief = "solid")

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Espero te pueda servir. ¡Saludos!

Comment: También podridas usar por ejemplo como parámetro  "activebackground = 'BLUE' " para que cuando presionen el botón se ponga azul. Aquí la documentación con todos los parametrios que te permite el comando button:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm